# Plotting count data in r

Tags: plot, count

I have counted crashes at intersections and am wondering how to plot this data in time series. The data was counted through the years of 2008 to 2018. the data is found at this link. Please, i am interested in the code and proper technique for plotting the data.

In order to get the data into table format the melt command from shape2 is required:

using `melt` from `reshape2`:

```
    > attidtudeM=melt(df)

    > head(attidtudeM)

      variable value
    1    F2008     0
    2    F2008     1
    3    F2008     1
    4    F2008     2
    5    F2008     0
    6    F2008     1

   > table(attidtudeM)

variable   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
   F2008 235  38  11   3   0   0   0   0
   F2009 244  27   8   6   2   0   0   0
   F2010 237   9  31   3   2   2   3   0
   F2011 241  33  11   0   1   0   1   0
   F2012 246  31   8   1   1   0   0   0
   F2013 251  28   7   1   0   0   0   0
   F2014 265  16   5   0   0   1   0   0
   F2015 261   6  17   0   2   0   1   0
   F2016 263  17   5   0   1   0   0   1
   F2017 275   7   4   0   0   0   0   1
```

```html
F2008   F2009   F2010   F2011   F2012   F2013   F2014   F2015   F2016   F2017
    1           1   1               
1   2   1               1   2   1   
1   1   2                           
2           1       2               
                                    
1           1                       
                3               1   
                                    
1   1   2           3   2   2   1   
        3           1               
        2                           
    1                               
                                    
                                    
1   1   4   1   1           2   2   2
                                    
                                    
2                               1   
        2   1       1   1       1   2
1   3   2   2       1   5   4   1   7
                                    
                                    
                1                   
2       2                           
1       6   2   1       2   1   1   2
1       2   1                       
        5           2   1   2       
                                    
        2   1                   1   
                                    
        1   2   2           1       
                                    
                                    
            2           2           
1                                   
                    1               
            1                       
1       0                           
                                    
                                    
                                    1
                4
```

Comment: Are you asking for the code to make a particular type of plot, or are you asking for advice on what sort of plot is the most appropriate for this sort of data? If it's the latter, you might be better asking on cross-validated (or perhaps data science)

Comment: Hi JDL, thanks for taking the time to read my post.  I am interested in advice.  More specifically, what code is necessary for  time series plot.

Comment: Have you looked at `ts.plot`?

Comment: HI JDL, ts.plot works! thank you.